# Does Array.sort() on a single-item array return without firing the callback function?

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion

I'm leveraging Array.sort() to recursively sort an array of objects, each of which may have children.

```html
window.sortByrecent = function (a, b) {
  if(a.children && !a.isSorted) {
    a.children = a.children.sort(window.sortByrecent);
    a.isSorted = true;
  }

  if(b.children && !b.isSorted) {
    b.children = b.children.sort(window.sortByrecent);
    b.isSorted = true;
  }

  // Later post comes first
  return moment(b.date).unix() - moment(a.date).unix();
}
```

This is kicked off by

```html
this.comments.sort(window.sortByrecent);
```

Certain sets of posts, however, don't get sorted, and I'm trying to figure out why. Stepping through it in the debugger, it looks like if you a.children is an array of one, it never actually fires the recursive callback, meaning that it never checks that comment's children, and thus never sorts them.

Is there a way to force the recursion?

--------  The Answer --------

```js
this.comments = window.sortByrecent(this.comments);

window.sortByrecent = function (arr) {
  if(!arr.isSorted) {
    arr.sort(window.compareByRecentNewFirst);

    arr.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
      if(array[index].children) {
       array[index].children = window.sortByrecent(array[index].children);
      }
    });

    arr.isSorted = true;
  }

  return arr;
}

window.compareByRecentNewFirst = function(a, b) {
  return moment(b.date).unix() - moment(a.date).unix();
}
```

Comment: I'd guess whether it gets called is implementation-dependent, the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) doesn't allow you to ask for it. Note that sort is in-place, so you don't need to assign the result back to the same prop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - My initial implementation was in-place, I was trying a number of things to figure out why my children weren't getting sorted.

Comment: It would make much more sense for `sort` *not* to call the callback function, since you don't have two distinct values to pass it.  It would bother me to find out that it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally should not sort (or perform side-effects) inside a `.sort` callback, because:

- The order in which elements are compared against each other may be implementation-dependent
- If the side-effects (such as sorting subproperties) are expensive, you may be needlessly carrying them out way more times than is needed. Sorting is an `O(n log n)` process; you don't need to sort each subarray `log n` times, you just need to sort each 1 time.

You'll probably want something like this instead:

```
const recursiveSort = arr => {
  if (!arr.isSorted) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => moment(b.date).unix() - moment(a.date).unix());
    for (const { children } of arr) {
      if (children) recursiveSort(children);
    }
    arr.isSorted = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok, so the logic moves outside of the sort, and the sort itself is scoped strictly to the date comparison. I'll try this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the sortings and use recursive function whocj sorts only onve for each nested array.

```
const
    sortByRecent = (a, b) => moment(b.date).unix() - moment(a.date).unix(),
    sort = (array) => {
        array.sort(sortByRecent);
        array.forEach(({ children = [] }) => sort(children));
    };
```

call with

```
sort(array);
```